# Efficiently creating sparse matrix from a disk on the surface of the Earth

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, geospatial, sparse-matrix

Given:

- a disk on the surface of the Earth, defined as a lat+long origin and a distance in meters
- a latitude/longitude grid, defined as a vector of latitudes and a vector of longitudes

I need to construct a sparse matrix which has one virtual cell for each point on the grid (so, its shape is `(len(longitudes), len(latitudes))`); it should be zero for all grid points outside the disk and a constant nonzero value for all grid points inside the disk.  The grid is big - covers the entire surface of the Earth from latitude -60 to +85 at a spacing of roughly 10km at the Equator.

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
import pyproj
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPoint
from shapely.ops import transform as sh_transform
WGS84_globe = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong', ellps='WGS84')
from functools import partial

def Disk(x, y, radius):
    return Point(x, y).buffer(radius)

def disk_to_matrix(latitudes, longitudes, ref_lat, ref_lon, max_dist):
    # half of the equatorial circumference of the Earth, in meters
    # it is impossible for the target to be farther away than this
    max_dist = min(max_dist, 20037508)

    # To find all points on the Earth within a certain distance of
    # a reference latitude and longitude, back-project onto the
    # Earth from an azimuthal-equidistant map with its zero point
    # at the reference latitude and longitude.
    projection = pyproj.Proj(
        proj='aeqd', ellps='WGS84', lat_0=ref_lat, lon_0=ref_lon)
    to_globe = partial(
        sh_transform,
        partial(pyproj.transform, projection, WGS84_globe))

    # pyproj (and therefore shapely) does everything in lon/lat order.
    grid = MultiPoint(list(
        (lon, lat)
        for lon in longitudes
        for lat in latitudes
    ))

    outer_ring = to_globe(Disk(0, 0, max_dist))
    ringpoints = grid.intersection(outer_ring)

    # scipy.sparse juggling goes here
```

I'm stuck at this point because *just attempting to create the MultiPoint instance* made the interpreter spin for fifteen minutes before I hit <kbd>^C</kbd>.  This needs to be super, super fast because it's only one step of the innermost loop of an algorithm that will iterate over *thousands* of these disks.  I could pre-create it but that would make the script take more than fifteen minutes just to start up, and I have this horrible feeling that the intersection operation and the matrix construction will also be unacceptably slow.  Suggestions?

(Bonus points for an algorithm that works when the value for each point inside the disk should be a nontrivial function of the distance from the zero point.)

Comment: So what would the shape of this sparse matrix be?

Comment: @Will `(len(longitudes), len(latitudes))` - I thought that was obvious, but I'll clarify.

Comment: Does it have to be a projection and a sparse matrix with lat/long?  A better data structure might be to map the sphere to a cube then represent each side with a quadtree.  In a point representation, a disk of radius M is of size O(M^2), and intersection is the same.  In this representation it is of size O(M) and intersection is also O(M).  (Even faster if you use tricks for representing the bounding line.)

Comment: What proportion of the values in your array are zero?  There is a `sparse` matrix class in `scipy`, but that is most useful when 90% of the values are 0.  Or are the values outside of this disk supposed to something else like `nan` of `None`?

Comment: Most likely going through shapely is why this is slow. If the size of the grid allows it, maybe just transform a `numpy.meshgrid` of the lat/lon's to `aeqs` coordinates and do some processing on that?